# Сменить язык сообщений csc

Tags: .net

Можно ли сделать чтобы `csc` выдавал сообщения на английском?

Comment: Хм. Удалить локализованные ресурсы у компилятора?

Comment: Загляните в каталог `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. Каталоги типа `1031`, `de` и `de-DE` содержат локализованные ресурсы. Попробуйте убрать их оттуда (лучше сохранить на всякий случай).

Comment: [Вот так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096249/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-the-microsoft-c-sharp-compilers-error-messages). То есть скачать языковой пакет с инглишем с микрософта.

Comment: Нету какого-нибудь ключика для командной строки?

Comment: `csc /?` по поводу языка молчит как партизан

Comment: @VladD Есть, почему, `/preferreduilang` ключ, его можно поюзать.

Comment: @Vesper у меня его нет.

Comment: @Vesper: Хм, и правда, есть, в секции advanced

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать в списке параметров ключ `/preferreduilang:en-us`. Например, `.\csc.exe /? /preferreduilang:en-us` выводит справку по команде на английском языке. Доступно в версии 4.5, не раньше.

Comment: v4.0.30319: не работает

Comment: А у меня пашет, специально проверил. Windows 7 x64, csc x64 тоже, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319> .\csc.exe /? /preferreduilang:en-us` выдал мне справку на инглише. А у вас установлен language pack от инглиша?

Comment: Кстати да, чтобы справку на английском вывести, нужно иметь папку 1033 в каталоге фреймворка. Если её нет, разговора не будет, будет использоваться дефолтная (нет языка - упсЪ). Сейчас проверил в программах - да, стоят две версии .NET 4.5.2, русская и английская.

Comment: Установлен. Рядом есть мой ответ с вариантов который у меня заработал. Более того, у меня /? такого ключа не выдает (по хорошему надо было матюкнуться на это)

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Посмотрите в секции advanced, там у меня нашёлся.

Comment: @VladD смотрел грепом, не нашлось. windows xp 32 bit

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Ага, в этом может быть разница. Допишите системные требования в вопрос, чтобы не было путаницы.

Comment: А какой .NET стоит? 4.0 или 4.5? Папка одна и та же, что в 4.0, что в 4.5.

Comment: @VladD насколько я понимаю, если не указаны требования, подразумевается маскимально широкая поддержка. Или это обязательно писать явно?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: Ну, если для старых версий нужен workaround, а старые работают «из коробки»... Например: thread в новом C++ — это просто `std::thread`, а в старом — `BeginThreadEx` или `pthread_create` или ещё как-нибудь там.

Comment: @VladD новых версий чего? У меня такой же framework v.4. Или нужно до 4.5 проапгрейдиться?

Comment: Кстати, сверьте, пожалуйста, какой билд указан у `csc.exe`, на котором нет такого пункта. А про 4.5 на ХР - [Микрософт фигу показывает](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp.aspx), к сожалению,

Comment: @Vesper Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1

Comment: Угу, 4.0 и без обновлений безопасности. Мда, печально, у меня вообще 4.5.2, и версия 4.0.30319.34238. И похоже, для винХР ответ "удалить другие языки" вполне подходит, остальным с установленным .NET 4.5 подходит мой.

Answer (score 0):

VladD подсказал:

Переименовываем/перемещаем из `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` все каталоги вида `1049`, кроме `1033` (английская локализация), но это, конечно, костылик.

Comment: В итоге для Windows XP и фреймворка ниже 4.5 другого варианта, похоже, не существует.